# How to resolve error while creating react app using npx

Tags: reactjs, npm

Hello I am trying to create a react app I read the documentation that I first have to run this command if I had installed. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` I did that because I had installed initially then thereafter I run the following command that they said on the docs that one should run to ensure that npx is running on the latest version: `npx create-react-app FirstApp`

**I then go this following error message:**

Install for ['create-react-app@latest'] failed with code 7

**So I then checked if I do have installed node properly I then ran:**

npm -v my version being 6.13.4

So I am wondering if this has to do with the version or something else?

Comment: you cannot use uppercase in your project folder name. You should try " npx create-react-app first-app ".

Comment: Just tried right now I am getting the same error

Comment: You’ll need to have Node >= 8.10 and npm >= 5.6 on your machine. Did you check your Node js version as well ?

Comment: That works for me I just downloaded latest Node and now everything works just fine